# Factor / level order with ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having a difficult time understanding how factor labels interact with legends. How do I set the order of levels so that the ggplot2 system creates a legend that I envision?

In the below code, the plot associate the Reds with the negative side of the interval and the blues with the positive.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(RColorBrewer)

set.seed(1492)  #discovery!
sample = data.frame(x = c(1:20), y = 1, obs = runif(20, -150, 150))
the.breaks = seq(-100, 100, by = 20)

sample$interval = factor(findInterval(sample$obs, vec = the.breaks, all.inside = TRUE), 
    labels = the.breaks, levels = c(1:length(the.breaks)))

pal = rev(brewer.pal(11, "RdBu"))

p = ggplot(sample, aes(x, y, colour = interval))
p = p + geom_point(size = 10)
p = p + scale_colour_manual(values = pal, limits = the.breaks, labels = the.breaks)
p = p + guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 3, shape = 19)))
p
```

This works fine, but I really don't like the

```
pal = rev(brewer.pal(11, "RdBu"))
```

statement - seems inelegant. I'd like to be able to replace the use of scale_colour_manual with something like

```
p = p + scale_colour_brewer(palette="RdBu", type="div", limits = the.breaks, labels = the.breaks)
```

but when I do, the Reds get associated with the positive end.

Answer (score 0):

You can order your factor levels in any way you like, this should help you get them the right colours. Try [this explanation](https://kohske.wordpress.com/2010/12/29/faq-how-to-order-the-factor-variables-in-ggplot2/) or any others out there on ordering factor levels. Note that the opts command in the blog post is out-dated.

Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887342/ggplot2-plotting-order-of-factors-within-a-geom).

And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064146/order-bars-within-each-factor-using-ggplot2) as well.